# Matplotlib tight_layout set rect tuple

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, figure

I have created the following code, which prints a plot and formats the axis labels and ticks in a way that is useful to me. I have a problem with tight_layout, which leaves my vertically rotated x-axis tick labels as well as the x-axis label outside the figure window.

To try and solve the problem, what I did was to manually rescale the plot window, and set the rect tuple manually from the figure window. After some tries, I found that the optimal values for (left, bottom, right, top) in my case were [0.163, 0.391, 0.905, 0.977]. Next, I thought I should incorporate that to my code, so that my plots emerge with correct sizing in the first place: To that end, I used the command:

> fig.tight_layout(rect=[0.163, 0.391, 0.905, 0.977])

However, it did not work, and the figure emerges with different rect values than the ones I set.

**Question 1:** How can I set the rect values from my code, rather than setting them manually?

**Question 2:** Is there a better/easier alternative to achieve the desired functionality?

```
# dt_objects is a list of datetime objects. My x-axis is timestamps
# for y_axis, set any series. The code will set the y axis based on the min,max value of y-values

matdates=date2num(dt_objects)
x_axis=matdates

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot_date(x_axis,y_axis,markersize=8)
ax.axhline(y=y_axis.mean(),linestyle='--',color='red',alpha=0.5)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(AutoDateLocator(minticks=1, maxticks=5))         #Set position of Major X ticks
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoDateLocator(minticks=10, maxticks=30))       #Set position of Minor X ticks
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter( DateFormatter('%Y/%m/%d-%H:%M:%S'))           #Set format of Major X ticks
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter( DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S'))                    #Set format of X ticks
ax.tick_params(axis='x',which='major',rotation=90,labelsize=14)                          #Set parameters of Major X ticks    
ax.tick_params(axis='x',which='minor',rotation=80,labelsize=12)                          #Set parameters of Major X ticks      
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), fontsize=14, fontweight="bold")              #Set font of Major X ticks  

ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.2f'))                    #Set format of Major Y ticks
ax.tick_params(axis='y',which='major',labelsize=14)
calculateYpadding=(y_axis.max()-y_axis.min())*0.1                           # Padding is 10% of the max difference in y values :)
ax.set_ylim(round(y_axis.min(),2)-calculateYpadding, round(y_axis.max(),2)+calculateYpadding)         #Set boundaries of Y axis
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(nbins = 'auto',min_n_ticks = 5)) 
plt.grid()

ax.set_xlabel("Time",style='italic',fontsize=14)
ax.xaxis.set_label_coords(1.08, -0.1)

ax.set_ylabel(str(MeasurementType),labelpad=10,style='italic', fontsize=14)
#ax.yaxis.set_label_coords(-0.1, 0.5)
#plt.xlabel("Time",horizontalalignment='right', position=(1,60))\
    
#ax.set_title(str(MeasurementType),fontweight="bold", pad=20,fontsize=20)
rstButton.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
fig.tight_layout(rect=[0.163, 0.391, 0.905, 0.977])
plt.show()
```

**EDIT:** Since I was told my question is not clear, I am including two screenshots to better explain the problem. Here is the result of the above-mentioned code. Also, on the bottom left, you can see on the window that top, bottom, left, right have different values than the ones set at rect tuple in my code.

[image]

My desired output is this:

[image]

It is achieved by manually tweaking the parameters of the figure, until it reaches a point that is satisfactory. It is from here that i extracted the values and placed them in the rect tuple, but it did not work. Hopefully it is clearer now what I want to achieve, and what the problem is.

**EDIT 2:** Here are the results of the suggested solution

> ```
> fig,ax = plt.subplots(constrained_layout=True)
> ```

As you can see, the labels of both axles are not correctly placed.

[image]

Comment: Its really not at all clear what you are trying to do, and this is not a reproducible piece of code.  However, it seems highly unlikely you want the rect to be `[0.907, 0.392, 0.907, 0.977]`.  Please read https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.tight_layout.html#matplotlib.pyplot.tight_layout for the meaning of the rect kwarg.  Also please consider reading  https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/tight_layout_guide.html and https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/constrainedlayout_guide.html

Comment: @JodyKlymak Please see my edit for better explanations, hopefully it will be more helpful. As for the rect tuple, the initial ones were wrong as you said, I changed them to what I believe "should" work but is not.

Comment: Yes, that is true, nothing will automatically work for what you want and you will need to set things by hand.  horizontal space is made for the ylabel, but not vertical space, because that leads to impossible situations.  You should just make the figure larger and/or use smaller labels.  I also would not insist on putting "Time" on the far right like that. If your viewer doesn't know that those labels are times, they probably aren't going to understand too much else.

Comment: Finally, your time tick labels are pretty wasteful, in terms of space.  You might consider https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/ticks_and_spines/date_concise_formatter.html

Answer (score -1):

Try:

`fig, ax = plt.subplots(constrained_layout=True)`

Comment: I tried your suggestion and I received the following warning: " UserWarning: Tight layout not applied. The left and right margins cannot be made large enough to accommodate all axes decorations. 
  fig.tight_layout(rect=[0.907, 0.392, 0.907, 0.977]) "   Needless to say, the desired functionality is still not achieved. Any ideas?

Comment: You can’t use constrained layout and tight layout together.  If you left the tight layout call in there, you never tried constrained layout.

Comment: I never told to use them together. btw sorry

Comment: Okay, I tried it without tight_layout, but still, the x-label and the y-label are not included whole in the figure window. See EDIT 2 for your solution results.